# Cumulative Counts and the Dates the Counts Become Negative and Positive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below scenario

```
Date     Amount Item 
6/17/08 208  1 
9/24/08  -48     1 
6/15/09  -160    1 
9/23/09  40      1
```

For the same items, I want to get the date where the cumulative amount is less than or equal to 0 the first time 
and if the cumulative amount becomes positive later, I want to get the date it turned positive as well.

```
Date     Amount Item Cumulative Amount 
6/17/08   208    1   208 
9/24/08  -48     1       160 
6/15/09  -160    1        0 --This date 
9/23/09  40      1        40 --This date
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT  date
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS csum,
                SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS psum
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   (csum <= 0 AND psum > 0)
        OR
        (csum > 0 AND psum <= 0)
```

In earlier versions:

```
SELECT  date
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                (
                SELECT  SUM(amount)
                FROM    mytable mi
                WHERE   mi.item = m.item
                        AND mi.date < m.date
                ) AS psum
        FROM    mytable m
        ) q
WHERE   (psum + amount <= 0 AND psum > 0)
        OR
        (psum + amount > 0 AND psum <= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the date when it first turns non-positive:

```
SELECT MIN(t3.Date) AS dateCumAmountTurnsLTEZero
FROM
(SELECT Date, 
 (SELECT SUM(Amount)
  FROM mytable t1
  WHERE t1.Date <= t2.Date) AS cumulativeAmount
 FROM mytable t2) t3
 WHERE t3.cumulativeAmount <= 0
```

To get the date it turns positive again you could either inject this result into another query or assuming you want to do it all in SQL it gets a bit hairy! See below:

```
SELECT MIN(t6.Date)
FROM
(SELECT Date, 
 (SELECT SUM(Amount)
  FROM mytable t4
  WHERE t4.Date <= t5.Date) AS cumulativeAmount
 FROM mytable t5) t6
WHERE t6.cumulativeAmount >= 0
AND t6.Date >
(SELECT MIN(t3.Date)
 FROM
 (SELECT Date, 
  (SELECT SUM(Amount)
   FROM mytable t1
   WHERE t1.Date <= t2.Date) AS cumulativeAmount
  FROM mytable t2) t3
  WHERE t3.cumulativeAmount <= 0)
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bed64/8)